# Ubuntu 16.04 server random reboots

Tags: server, reboot

My Ubuntu server reboots itself at random times. At first I suspected automatic updates, even though that would be strange on a fresh server install. I did make sure it was disabled.

I can find nothing in dmesg, syslog or kern.log about the cause.

What's really weird is the entries in "last reboot"

```
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-21-generic Thu Apr 28 17:06   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-21-generic Mon Apr 25 20:32   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-21-generic Mon Apr 25 20:25 - 20:31  (00:05)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-21-generic Sat Apr 23 20:40 - 20:31 (1+23:51)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-21-generic Sat Apr 23 19:16 - 20:39  (01:23)
```

According to this the previous boot is still running?

Uptime says

```
 23:10:41 up  6:04,  1 user,  load average: 0,00, 0,01, 0,05
```

so the server did reboot.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem was a bad PSU

Answer (score 5):

If so your system is not crashing, it is rebooting to install an update that requires a reboot.

Automatic reboots are controlled in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`.  The line that controls it begins `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot` and take a `true` or `false` value.  If you don't allow automatic reboots, you should be notified that a reboot is required when you login.

There are other packages besides unattended-upgrades that can trigger a reboot.  They should all invoke apt to do the upgrade.  Check `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see if updates are occurring before the reboot.

If the reboots are occurring at roughly the same time, then there may be something in the crontabs that is causing the reboots.

If the system really is crashing, it may be the BIOS which is rebooting the system.  You may want to change the power on state setting.

#### Commands

1. `dmesg` - very useful if the system is still up

#### Files

1. `/var/log/syslog` - System wide logger, use `tail /var/log/syslog` or `less /var/log/syslog`
2. `/var/log/kern.log` - Kernel log, same as above
3. `/var/log/*`

Check `cat /proc/sys/kernel/panic`, if it's value is 1 then server will immediately reboot on panic. Bad drivers/hw/software can cause kernel panic.

If it's not panic check last issue of reboot, maybe overheating is the issue.

```
last reboot
```